# HowTo Jhipster microservices and Gateway WITH codenvy?

Tags: jhipster, codenvy

I wish there's a trick for coding jHipster Microservices and Gateway with Codenvy, even with these issues related in the below closed isssue.
This closed issue comes from Jhipster, which is reason why I ask here, so please see it carefully if interested by topic of the question.

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6922

This is a screenshot from my codenvy machine:

[image: Screenshot from my codenvy machine]

Please help and tell me, as I keep thinking that with an advanced use of BrowserSync, we could finally manage this.

I already have a Codenvy with 7GB which let run all the stack tiers simultaneously. Yet I can test the apps but not perfectly , as you can see if you follow the related ticket. I can pass thru the entities creation forms, yet once I come to call the CRUD rest services, it's failing because listen ports are not accessible => seems like due to redirections, my local browser is trying to access open ports from the realm, but Codenvy only give 1 virtual access to a single test port.

What I'd like to do with BrowserSync is just manipulating a headLess browser on the Codenvy machine, remotly from my Codenvy test URL. Then all problems would be solved no? Is this possible?